# Was the Psych theme song written for the show?

Tags: soundtrack, psych

The Friendly Indians sing the theme song for USA's show *Psych*. Was that song written *for the show* or was it previously an existing song which was used in the *Psych* opening credits?

Comment: Off-topic: [Band of Horses - The funeral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMFWFhTFohk) is still my favorite from that amazing series!

Comment: @gsamaras I'm missing what that has to do with the question? Was that song in one of the episodes?

Comment: @JPhi1618 absolutely, in that AWESOME επεισόδιο with Julie being kept in the roof of a tall building, where she almost died... And that song kicked in just in the right moment, I searched restlessly the Internet to find that piece of music back then... The episode, maybe one of the best of the series too - along with that one where Shawn's father is shot and the season finishes - is "Mr. Yin Presents...".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The song "The Best Man Lies" was included on The Friendly Indians' EP *Tiny Badness*, released in 2004.

[image: list of songs included in the album]

A version song was re-released as "I know, You know" in 2006 after it became popular as the show's theme song.  Additional versions of the song were recorded for specific episodes of the show, sometimes using different performers.

Comment: So it _wasn't_ written for the show? In that case, you're disagreeing with @sanpaco's answer.

Comment: sanpaco's answer makes the unsupported assumption that being written and performed by the show's creator automatically means that it was created for the show.  Even if I didn't know the song was included on an album from several years earlier, the leap of logic in that answer would leave me with doubts about it's accuracy.

Comment: This opens up the possibility that the show was written for the song.

Comment: You're right, in fact the link I sourced gives this same info, I just didn't read the whole thing. My bad :)